# Fetch data from a large file based on time and date recursively

Tags: text-processing, awk, python, r

Fetch data based on date(column 1) and time (column 2). Each date has time in column 2. Based on each date in column1 two files are to be generated which will have all the fields based on time 6:00 to 21:50:08 (day) and 22:00:00 to 5:50:00 (night). Trying to get two files for each date as date_day and date_night based on the times specified.

Input file:

```
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 19:00:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/10/2023 19:10:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
03/10/2023 19:20:08 18.68   39.940  4.80
03/10/2023 19:30:08 18.84   40.110  5.01
03/10/2023 19:40:08 18.89   38.960  4.64
03/10/2023 19:50:08 18.60   39.100  4.43
03/10/2023 23:30:08 18.03   34.200  2.03
03/10/2023 23:40:08 17.94   33.930  1.84
03/10/2023 23:50:08 17.87   33.840  1.74
03/11/2023 00:00:08 17.75   33.790  1.61
03/11/2023 00:10:08 17.96   34.060  1.91
03/11/2023 00:20:08 18.13   33.690  1.91
03/11/2023 00:30:08 17.91   33.620  1.68
```

Output files:

`03/10/2023_day`

```
Date        Time    R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 19:00:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/10/2023 19:10:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
03/10/2023 19:20:08 18.68   39.940  4.80
03/10/2023 19:30:08 18.84   40.110  5.01
03/10/2023 19:40:08 18.89   38.960  4.64
```

`03/10/2023_night`

```
Date        Time     R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 19:50:08 18.60   39.100  4.43
03/10/2023 23:30:08 18.03   34.200  2.03
03/10/2023 23:40:08 17.94   33.930  1.84
03/10/2023 23:50:08 17.87   33.840  1.74
```

`03/11/2023_night`:

```
Date       Time      R1     R2      R3
03/11/2023 00:00:08 17.75   33.790  1.61
03/11/2023 00:10:08 17.96   34.060  1.91
03/11/2023 00:20:08 18.13   33.690  1.91
03/11/2023 00:30:08 17.91   33.620  1.68
```

I tried the following to fetch day and night files. This I will have to do for each date again and again. I removed the ':' from the time column in my code to get a number without :. Can anyone please help to put it in a loop and the separate day and night files for each date?

```
awk '$1 ~ /03\/10\/2023/ && $2 >= 060000 && $2 <= 215000' data |sed 's/\t/,/g' > 03_10_23_day.csv
awk '$1 ~ /03\/10\/2023/ && $2 > 215000' data |sed 's/\t/,/g' > 03_10_23_night.csv
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively"?

Comment: You've given a 'night' time range (22:00:00 to 5:50:00) that crosses midnight. So  it seems you actually want three files per date [not two]: early morning (00:00:00 to 5:50:00), day (6:00:00 to 21:50:08), and night 22:00:00 to 23:59:59). Correct?

Comment: `sed 's/\t/,/g'` implies *a)* the input is tab delimited (but it's not) and *b)* the output is to be comma delimited (but it's not); please update the question to insure the description, sample data sets and sample code *match*

Comment: filenames containing `/` are typically not allowed in most  OS's; since your sample code appears to be replacing `/` with `_` (in the output file names), it would appear the question needs further editing to insure sample output filenames are valid and match the output filenames from sample sample code

Comment: @jubilatious1 Just two files after 21:50:08 to 5:50:08 is night and the rest is day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want string comparisons rather than number comparisons in `awk` and generate all output files in one `awk` invocation. Using a loop wouldn't make sense here:

```bash
awk -v OFS=, '
  {$1 = $1} # force reformatting with comma delimiters
  NR == 1 {header = $0; next}
  {
    split($1, f, "/")
    outfile = f[1] "_" f[2] "_" substr(f[3], 3) "_" \
              ($2 >= "06:00:00" && $2 < "22:00:00" ? "day" : "night") \
              ".csv"
    if (!seen[outfile]++) print header > outfile
    print > outfile
  }' < data
```

(`$2 >= "06" && $2 < "22"` would also work here)

I'd suggest naming your files `2023-10-03-night.csv` rather than `03_10_23_night.csv` (assuming it's meant to be the third of October rather than the tenth of March) which would mean `ls` for instance would show them in chronological order and that `2023-10-03` is an international standard unambiguous format.

Comment: Great! Much appreciated, Stephane. Could you please help me understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
#OUTPUT A SPECIFIED 'TIME-OF-DAY' RANGE FOR ALL DATES IN FILE:

~$ raku -e 'my $hdr = get; my @a = lines.map: *.split(" ");  \
            my @b = do for @a { .[0..1].join("T").subst(/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**4) /, {"$2-$0-$1"} ).DateTime, .[2..*] };  \
            put $hdr; for @b {   \
                my $start = .[0].truncated-to("day") + Duration.new(21600);  \
                my $stop  = .[0].truncated-to("day") + Duration.new(71408);  \
                put $_ if  $_.[0] ~~ $start ..^ $stop };'  file
```

Above (first answer) is an approach using Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. An advantage of using Raku is that `ISO-8601` [DateTimes](https://docs.raku.org/type/DateTime) are built-in. Above filters lines of input, giving output within a defined `$start .. $stop` range. The `..^` range operator (with caret) excludes the RHS timepoint from output.

```perl
#OUTPUT A 'TIME-OF-DAY' RANGE FOR A SPECIFIED DATE IN FILE:

~$ raku -e 'my $target_date = DateTime.new("2023-03-10");   \
            say $target_date; my $hdr = get;  \
            my @a = lines.map: *.split(" "); my @b = do for @a { .[0..1].join("T").subst(/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**4) /, {"$2-$0-$1"} ).DateTime, .[2..*] };  \
            put $hdr;  for @b {   \
                my $start = $target_date + Duration.new(21600);  \
                my $stop  = $target_date + Duration.new(71408);  \ 
                put $_ if  $_.[0] ~~ $start ..^ $stop };'    file
```

Above (second answer) somewhat more specifically you can define a `$target_date` and only retain a 'time-of-day' range for that Date in output.

Sample Input (OP's example plus two extra lines added at end):

```
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 19:00:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/10/2023 19:10:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
03/10/2023 19:20:08 18.68   39.940  4.80
03/10/2023 19:30:08 18.84   40.110  5.01
03/10/2023 19:40:08 18.89   38.960  4.64
03/10/2023 19:50:08 18.60   39.100  4.43
03/10/2023 23:30:08 18.03   34.200  2.03
03/10/2023 23:40:08 17.94   33.930  1.84
03/10/2023 23:50:08 17.87   33.840  1.74
03/11/2023 00:00:08 17.75   33.790  1.61
03/11/2023 00:10:08 17.96   34.060  1.91
03/11/2023 00:20:08 18.13   33.690  1.91
03/11/2023 00:30:08 17.91   33.620  1.68
03/12/2023 19:00:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/12/2023 19:10:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
```

Sample Output (1):

```
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
2023-03-10T19:00:08Z 19.06   39.870  5.12
2023-03-10T19:10:08Z 18.87   39.970  4.98
2023-03-10T19:20:08Z 18.68   39.940  4.80
2023-03-10T19:30:08Z 18.84   40.110  5.01
2023-03-10T19:40:08Z 18.89   38.960  4.64
2023-03-12T19:00:08Z 19.06   39.870  5.12
2023-03-12T19:10:08Z 18.87   39.970  4.98
```

Sample Output (2):

```
2023-03-10T00:00:00Z
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
2023-03-10T19:00:08Z 19.06   39.870  5.12
2023-03-10T19:10:08Z 18.87   39.970  4.98
2023-03-10T19:20:08Z 18.68   39.940  4.80
2023-03-10T19:30:08Z 18.84   40.110  5.01
2023-03-10T19:40:08Z 18.89   38.960  4.64
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/temporal
https://docs.raku.org/type/DateTime
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- output filenames are to convert dates from using `/` to dates using `_` (eg, `03/10/2023` becomes `03_10_2023`)
- output filenames are to be of the format `DD_MM_YYYY_day` or `DD_MM_YYY_night` - per expected outputs (ie, for this answer we'll ignore the `.csv` extentions as shown in OP's sample code)
- input/output field delimiters are white space - as per sample inputs/outputs (ie, for this answer we'll ignore the implied tab/comma delimiters from OP's `sed s/\t/,/g`)
- input data is already sorted by date (column #1) and time (column #2)
- time ranges are defined as follows (removing gaps introduced by OP's definitions):
- `day` = `06:00:00` to `21:59:59` (vs OP: `06:00:00` to `21:50:08` ???)
- `night` = `22:00:00` to `05:59:59` (vs OP: `22:00:00` to `05:50:00` ???)
- the `03/10/2023 19:50:08` entry should reside in the resulting `_day` file and not the `_night` file (as OP has shown in the expected output)
- OP wants to place `0[0-5]` (early morning) entries in the date's `_night` file (as opposed to either *a)* placing in previous date's `_night` file or *b)* placing in a new `_morning` file)
- **NOTE:** if any of these assumptions/understandings are incorrect then OP will need to update the question to provide more details and clarity

Adding a couple more lines to sample input file:

```
$ cat data
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 03:10:08 19.06   39.870  5.12          # new: to be placed in '_night' file
03/10/2023 05:30:08 18.87   39.970  4.98          # new: to be placed in '_night' file
03/10/2023 19:00:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/10/2023 19:10:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
03/10/2023 19:20:08 18.68   39.940  4.80
03/10/2023 19:30:08 18.84   40.110  5.01
03/10/2023 19:40:08 18.89   38.960  4.64
03/10/2023 19:50:08 18.60   39.100  4.43
03/10/2023 23:30:08 18.03   34.200  2.03
03/10/2023 23:40:08 17.94   33.930  1.84
03/10/2023 23:50:08 17.87   33.840  1.74
03/11/2023 00:00:08 17.75   33.790  1.61
03/11/2023 00:10:08 17.96   34.060  1.91
03/11/2023 00:20:08 18.13   33.690  1.91
03/11/2023 00:30:08 17.91   33.620  1.68
```

**NOTE:** file does not contain comments

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NR==1               { hdr = $0; next }                        # save header

$1 != prev_dt       { close(out_day)                          # if new date then close output files
                      close(out_night)

                      prev_dt = out_dt = $1                   # make note of new date
                      gsub(/\//,"_",out_dt)                   # replace "/" with "_"

                      out_day   = out_dt "_day"               # define new output file names
                      out_night = out_dt "_night"

                      hdr_flag_day = hdr_flag_night = 1       # reset "print header?" flag
                    }

$2 >= "06:00:00" &&                                           # "day"
$2 <= "21:59:59"    { if ( hdr_flag_day ) {
                         print hdr > out_day
                         hdr_flag_day = 0
                      }
                      print $0 > out_day
                      next
                    }

                    { if ( hdr_flag_night ) {                 # "night"
                         print hdr > out_night
                         hdr_flag_night = 0
                      }
                      print $0 > out_night
                    }
' data
```

This generates:

```
$ head 03*20??_[dn]*
==> 03_10_2023_day <==
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 19:00:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/10/2023 19:10:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
03/10/2023 19:20:08 18.68   39.940  4.80
03/10/2023 19:30:08 18.84   40.110  5.01
03/10/2023 19:40:08 18.89   38.960  4.64
03/10/2023 19:50:08 18.60   39.100  4.43

==> 03_10_2023_night <==
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
03/10/2023 03:10:08 19.06   39.870  5.12
03/10/2023 05:30:08 18.87   39.970  4.98
03/10/2023 23:30:08 18.03   34.200  2.03
03/10/2023 23:40:08 17.94   33.930  1.84
03/10/2023 23:50:08 17.87   33.840  1.74

==> 03_11_2023_night <==
Date       Time     R1      R2      R3
03/11/2023 00:00:08 17.75   33.790  1.61
03/11/2023 00:10:08 17.96   34.060  1.91
03/11/2023 00:20:08 18.13   33.690  1.91
03/11/2023 00:30:08 17.91   33.620  1.68
```